# How does volatile keyword ensure an object`s fields are visible to other threads?

Tags: java, concurrency, volatile

```
public class ObjectPropertiesVolatileTest {

    static Cup cup = new Cup();

    public static void changeColor() {
        cup.setColor("black"); // change color of cup to black
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        cup.setColor("red"); // initialize color of cup as red

        for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            new Thread(){
                public void run() {
                    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
                        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()
                                + " " + i + " is " + cup.getColor());

                    if(Thread.currentThread().getName().equals("Thread-1"))
                        changeColor(); // Thread-1 changes the color of cup

                    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
                        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()
                                + " " +i + " is " + cup.getColor());

                }
            }.start();
        }

    }

}

class Cup {

    private volatile String color;

    public String getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public void setColor(String color) {
        this.color = color;
    }
}
```

My question is: how to ensure the field `color` of the object cup is visible to other threads only using `volatile` keyword instead of using synchronization or lock?

Comment: What you've done should work just fine, as far as I can see.  What's going wrong for you?

Comment: Seems to work fine. When `Thread-1` changes the color to `black`, all threads immediately begins printing `black`.

Comment: you dont need any synchronization nor volatiles if you write from single thread and read from multiple threads

Comment: If you run a few times more, you will see it does not work fine sometimes.

Comment: @Antoniossss that information is generally wrong. There are a few other ways besides volatile and synchronized, such as starting or joining a thread, but you do need to take precautions to ensure that the data is visible in other threads, and there is nothing special about one writing + multiple reading threads

Comment: @Antoniossss your statement there is so not true. read from even just a different thread from the write thread will need to ensure the visibility of the write operation is visible to the read so that any dependent operations based on the read thread will be able to see the changes made from the write thread. synchronization or volatile provides visibility for that purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it is working fine. The problem is that the printing, call to print statement, merging of strings in `System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " " +i + " is " + cup.getColor());`, etc. are not synchronised.

I added print statements to your getters/setters to log the time of calls:-

```
public String getColor() {
    System.out.println("-------------------------get " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + this.color + " " + System.nanoTime());
    return color;
}

public void setColor(String color) {
    System.out.println("-------------------------set " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + color + this.color + " " + System.nanoTime());
    this.color = color;
}
```

A snippet of what it printed:-

```
.
.
.
Thread-0 4 is red
-------------------------get Thread-1red 1356826035808750
Thread-1 8 is red
-------------------------get Thread-2red 1356826035425706
Thread-2 2 is red
-------------------------get Thread-1red 1356826035963697
Thread-1 9 is red
-------------------------get Thread-0red 1356826035894581
-------------------------set Thread-1blackred 1356826036165653
-------------------------get Thread-2red 1356826036036858
Thread-2 3 is black
-------------------------get Thread-1black 1356826036219728
Thread-1 0 is black
Thread-0 5 is red
-------------------------get Thread-1black 1356826036402925
Thread-1 1 is black
-------------------------get Thread-2black 1356826036305139
Thread-2 4 is black
-------------------------get Thread-1black 1356826036535236
Thread-1 2 is black
.
.
.
```

The problem you are concerned about is this line:-
`Thread-0 5 is red`
It should have printed `black`, right?

Well, this thread entered the getter before the other thread changed the value. This is evident from these lines:-

```
-------------------------get Thread-0red 1356826035894581
-------------------------set Thread-1blackred 1356826036165653
```

So it read the value correctly but the processing done after that took a long time as compared to the time taken by other threads in doing what they were doing.

Happy for someone to correct me if I am wrong. :)

Comment: In other words, `volatile` guarantees visibility, but the code still is settling on an entirely unspecified execution timing. And actually, side effects of the `System.out.println` operation (internal synchronization and buffer flushing on new lines) are preventing the worst race conditions here.