# happens-before relationship does not work as expected using "volatile"

Tags: java, multithreading, volatile, happens-before

```
int x,y;
volatile int z;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ThreadPoolExecutor pool = (ThreadPoolExecutor)Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
    MainTest mission = new MainTest();
    pool.execute(new MissionRead(mission));

    pool.execute(new MissionWrite(mission));
            pool.execute(new MissionWrite(mission));

    pool.shutdown();
}

public void set() {
    System.out.println("set start");
    x++;

    y++;z++;

    System.out.println("set end");

}

public void get() {
    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() +": get start");
    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() +": z is " + z);
    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + ": x is " +  x);
    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() +": y is " + y);
    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() +": get end");

}
```

output: pool-1-thread-1: get start
set start
set end
set start
set end
pool-1-thread-1: z is 0
pool-1-thread-1: x is 2
pool-1-thread-1: y is 2
pool-1-thread-1: get end

expected output: pool-1-thread-1: get start
set start
set end
set start
set end
pool-1-thread-1: z is 2
pool-1-thread-1: x is 2
pool-1-thread-1: y is 2
pool-1-thread-1: get end

why the output does not display the updated value of z with volatile keywords.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does volatile keyword ensure an object\`s fields are visible to other threads?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52470335/how-does-volatile-keyword-ensure-an-objects-fields-are-visible-to-other-threads)

Answer (score 0):

This is because being `volatile` would simply force a read on the main memory for any atomic action done to/with it, but `z++` is equivalent to `z = z + 1` which means there are 2 actions in there: a read operation and a write operation. Multiple threads can still read/write the value in between these 2 operations.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are looking for something like this: Use the `synchronized` keyword in your method. This ensures that the commands in this method are all executed as if it was only one statement. So nothing happens inbetween these statements.

```
public synchronized void set() {
    System.out.println("set start");
    x++;
    y++;
    z++;
    System.out.println("set end");
}
```

Comment: I think it is not caused by a read happens between the z++, as can see the 'set end' has printed twice, before printing out the value of 'z'.